# Get camera preview position in UIImagePickerController for iPhone 12

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a UIImagePickerController with showsCameraControls set to false. The camera preview position is being set to the center by using the cameraViewTransform property.

```
int cameraViewHeight = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width * (4.0 / 3.0);
            
int adjustedYPosition = ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height - cameraViewHeight) / 2;
            
self.imagePicker.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, adjustedYPosition);
```

Normally, the position is (0,0) when showsCameraControls is false. This changes with iPhone 12, in which it keeps the same position as when showsCameraControls is true (almost centered).

Is there a way to access the position of the camera preview, in order to calculate the corresponding transformation so it can be perfectly centered?

Comment: Did you find something for this?